# Simple slide animation doesn't work on several Firefox and Safari instalations while it works on both browsers on most computers

Tags: html, css, animation, slider, smarty

I have a problem with this code. It works on all browsers I have installed, but it doesn't work on my friends Mozilla, and the other friends Safari. It seems pretty random. They both use same operating system but one of them have a problem on one of these browsers while it works fine on the other. I also checked with a couple of other computers at work and it works fine.

The code is smarty template so there's conditional in this code that doesn't do anything special since I changed the code. I don't have any experience with Smarty and PHP but I thought that might be a problem.

I used auto prefixer to make it cross browser compatible.

HTML_

```css
.slide-jumbo{
  font-family: 'Bebas';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #ee7f01;
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: start;
  color: white;
  
}

.animate-jumbo-slide{
    -webkit-animation: slideIn 8s infinite;
            animation: slideIn 8s infinite;
}

 .slide-jumbo-2{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: start;
  
}

.slide-jumbo-2 h2{
  margin: 0;
  
}

.slide-jumbo-2 button{
  width: auto;
}


.slider-jumbo-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 40vw;
    left: 10vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 40%;
    display:
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideIn{
  0%   {-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);transform: translateX(100%)}
  30%   {-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);transform: translateX(100%)}
  40%  {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);transform: translateX(0%)}
  90%  {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);transform: translateX(0%)}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);transform: translateX(-100%)}
}

@keyframes slideIn{
  0%   {-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);transform: translateX(100%)}
  30%   {-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);transform: translateX(100%)}
  40%  {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);transform: translateX(0%)}
  90%  {-webkit-transform: translateX(0%);transform: translateX(0%)}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);transform: translateX(-100%)}
}
```

```html
{if $lista}
<div id="slider-area" class="owl-carousel" data-plugin-options='{literal}{"responsive": {"0": {"items": 1, "dots": true}, "480": {"items": 1, "dots": true}, "769": {"items": 1, "dots": false}, "992": {"items": 1, "dots": true}, "1200": {"items": 1, "dots": true}}, "nav" : false, "autoplaySpeed": 2000, "autoplayTimeout": 5000, "loop": false,"margin": 0}{/literal}'>
  {section name=slider loop=$lista}                
  <div class="slider-item" style="background-image:url('{$lista[slider].plik}')">
      <div class="slider-jumbo-container">
    <div class="slide-jumbo position-absolute animate-jumbo-slide">
        <h1>Title One</h1>
        <p>Text one</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-jumbo-2">
        <h1>Title Two</h1>
        <p class="d-none d-md-block">Text Two</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Click</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
  {/section} 
</div>
{/if}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Seems like your friends browser are to old to handle these cross browser codes.

Comment: I checked with them and their version is up to date. Also it was installed on a computer that's like a half year old so it's not likely that her version of mozilla is that 'ancient :\